# HTML5 - its possible use input type file to access the device camera library?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to do a request

http://ocrapiservice.com/documentation/

but I have an `<img>` and I need send this with post. I must use input type file? 
If yes, How can I use this to access the device library?

If no, how can I send this img with post?

I did try the follwoing code. But "choose file" in device is not working..

```
    <form action="http://api.ocrapiservice.com/1.0/rest/ocr" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000" />
            Choose a file to upload: <input name="image" type="file" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="language" value="pt" />
        <input type="text" name="apikey" value="keey" />

        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
```

Comment: They have example HTML usage at the link you pasted.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: What "*device*", what "*camera library*" are you talking of? What `<img>` element do you have?